# How can I "modularize" sections of my Bamboo Specs Java file?

Tags: java, bamboo-specs

We currently have multiple Bamboo plans that have common stages/jobs/tasks.  We just moved to using Bamboo Specs and I would like to pull each common section out into a single "module" so I only have to make changes in one location.  From what I have read this should be a possibility but cannot find any examples of this being done and I'm not a Java developer.

Can anyone let me know how to pull these out so I can make it common across multiple plans?

Comment: I have an example of repository here that you may use: https://bitbucket.org/renficiaud/bamboo-java-specs/ . Some explanations on the structure are given here: https://yayimorphology.org/bamboo-specs-project-sharing.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. When using YAML Specs, you can use the `!include 'file.yaml'` tag.
See https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/latest/specs.html?yaml#includes

Some things to remember:

- the file path of the included file is **always** relative to the `/bamboo-specs` directory
- You can include full YAML documents or objects
- Your YAML Spec file must still be valid YAML. (Note: `!include 'file.yaml' is considered a SCALAR value)

Valid syntax:
`Build: !include 'builds/build-job.yaml'`

Invalid syntax:
`Build:`
  `!include 'builds/build-job.yaml'`
  `description: builds project`
This is invalid because the value of Build cannot include both a scalar value and key-value pairs.

Invalid syntax (rejected syntax):
`Build: &buildJob !include 'builds/build-job.yaml'`